# How does the Azure AD B2C sign up policy integrate with an AngularJS Application?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I use AngularJS in frontend and web API in backend. I want for the project to redirect users to a custom login page. I added the sign up policy in Policy-User flow, but how can I integrate this policy to an AngularJS app, such that when the application runs it redirects to this page?

Answer (score 1):

Did you search for samples? Here is one: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-angular-spa